# kite not working on jupyter lab, but working on python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kite

my visual code version : 1.59

my jupyter lab version : 3.1.4

I've installed kite with command:

```
pip install "jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2"
```

after install kite, it work on python, but unsupported on file jupyter (.ipynb).
thank you for your help